# Can you pray mincha with a tzibur that's praying Maariv?

Tags: tefilla, minyan

Many times I find a maariv minyan praying before shkia, can I pray mincha with them? 
Is this considered tefila biTzibur?

Please provide sources to your answers.

Comment: Can you explain m e the side of the safek which says that it is not tefila betsibur?

Comment: @kouty You are not praying the same thing at all as the rest of the tzibbur - the structure and intent of their prayers does not match your own, and there will be no chazaras hashatz of your "mincha" shmone esrei. They're saying the Shema and its brachos you're not, an established minyan like the one referenced in the question is permitted to engage in tartei disasrei with their early ma'ariv and you as an individual can't *(and technically aren't?)*... So many reasons why you could argue that a late coming individual wouldn't be counted as part of that minyan...

Comment: @Issac One just needs to be present. He doesn't need to actually daven with the tzibbur. Why is it any worse when he's davening something else?